# How does Android establish data connection with a invalid APN?

Tags: android, apn

I have a HTC Explorer and I'm developing an app which sets APN settings in Android. The thing is that it seems like it doesn't matter whether I set the correct APN or not.
It still WORKS!!
Is the operator handling this on the server side? Does it work diffrently on GSM and CDMA? Maybe Android reads the settings from the SIM-card if available? Or last know working configuration?

How does it work?!

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it really works, but this might help. I found the APN settings for almost every carrier in the world is available in an XML file, you can get it with the following commands:

```
adb pull cust/nii/chile/xml/apns-conf.xml
```

I'm based in Chile, but there are folders for a couple more South American countries. For example, here's the APN settings for a Japanese carrier I found:

```
<!--begin niudahai DTS2010120102485 20101201-->
<apn carrier="SoftBank"
     apn="andglobal.softbank.ne.jp"
     proxy=""
     port=""
     user="andg004softbank"
     password="fp34vqgtu9nueeuk"
     server=""
     mmsc="http://mms/"
     mmsproxy="andmms.softbank.ne.jp"
     mmsport="8080"
     mcc="440"
     mnc="20"
 authtype="2"
     type="default,mms"
/>
```

So I guess the algorithm might be:

1. Try with the user-supplied APN settings.
2. If this doesn't work, find the available operators.
3. Apply the stored APN settings.

If you need a sample of the file I'll upload it somewhere.